# Adding gradle from cmd

Tags: windows, jsp, cmd

I want to add Gradle in an existing project using cmd

so I access the root of my project and type

```
C:\Users\MyUser\FaleMais>gradlew.bat war
```

then apear this wrong

```
 Gradlew.bat ' Is Not Recognized As an internal control
 OR external , operable program OR A FILE Batch .
```

**I should have any intaledd software as git or composer ?**

Comment: It looks like gradle isn't in your path ...

Comment: i find the solution, was missing install gradle and set environment variable here teach how https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxKN2VSqTMg